# How to add expression in collection query magento 2?

Tags: magento2, model

I want to write this query into Magento 2 formate

```
SELECT vendor_id, vendor_name, (
    6371 * ACOS( COS( RADIANS( 45.4102961 ) ) * COS( RADIANS( vendor_latitude ) ) * COS( RADIANS( vendor_longitude ) - RADIANS( - 93.2434978 ) ) + SIN( RADIANS( 45.4102961 ) ) * SIN( RADIANS( vendor_latitude ) ) )
    ) AS distance
    FROM udropship_vendor
    HAVING distance <30
    ORDER BY distance
    LIMIT 0 , 20
```

Here is my query

```
$collection = $this->vendor->create();
    $collection->addFieldToSelect(array('vendor_id', 'vendor_name', 'vendor_latitude', 'vendor_longitude', 'zip', 'street', 'city'));
    $collection>addExpressionFieldToSelect('distance', new Zend_Db_Expr('( 6371 * acos( cos( radians('.$latitudeFrom.') ) * cos( radians( {{vendor_latitude}}) ) * cos( radians( {{vendor_longitude}}) - radians('.$longitudeFrom.') ) + sin( radians('.$latitudeFrom.') ) * sin( radians( {{vendor_latitude}}) ) ) )'), array('vendor_latitude'=>'vendor_latitude', 'vendor_longitude'=>'vendor_longitude'));

    $collection->getSelect()->having('distance > 10');

    return $collection;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: use this https://webkul.com/blog/magento2-write-custom-mysql-query/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi thank you for help the answers is here

Please make sure your collection is extending

```
\Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection
```

You can use with pagination like this method

```
public function getNearestVendorList()
{
    $page=($this->getRequest()->getParam('p'))? $this->getRequest()->getParam('p') : 1;
    $pageSize=($this->getRequest()->getParam('limit'))? $this->getRequest()->getParam('limit') : 5;
    $redious = 50;

    $cookieValue = $this->helper->getCookie();
    if($cookieValue){
        $latitudeFrom = $cookieValue['latitude'];
        $longitudeFrom = $cookieValue['longitude'];
    }else{
        $latitudeFrom = $this->helper->getDefaultLatitude();
        $longitudeFrom = $this->helper->getDefaultLongitude();
    }
    $distance = $this->helper->getDistanceRadious();

    $collection = $this->vendor->create();
    $collection->addFieldToSelect(['vendor_id', 'vendor_name', 'vendor_latitude', 'vendor_longitude', 'zip', 'street', 'city']);
    $collection->setPageSize($pageSize);
    $collection->setCurPage($page);
    $collection->addExpressionFieldToSelect('distance', '( 6371 * acos( cos( radians('.$latitudeFrom.') ) * cos( radians( {{vendor_latitude}}) ) * cos( radians( {{vendor_longitude}}) - radians('.$longitudeFrom.') ) + sin( radians('.$latitudeFrom.') ) * sin( radians( {{vendor_latitude}}) ) ) )', array('vendor_latitude'=>'vendor_latitude', 'vendor_longitude'=>'vendor_longitude'));

    return $collection;
}
```

Comment: Thanx @sarfaraz Ahmed